# how to switch between windows (NOT TABS) in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Whenever login button is clicked a new window (NOT TAB) is opened I want to switch to opened window here is my code please me out its not working fine(driver is not switching to other window).

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Users\atif.ali\Desktop\Driver\chromedriver.exe");

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://release01.curemd.com/curemd/datLogin.asp");
    //driver.get("https://release01.curemd.com/curemd/datCureMD.aspx");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"vchLogin_Name\"]")).sendKeys("zlive");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"vchPassword\"]")).sendKeys("1234");
    //*[@id="frmLogin"]/div[3]/button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"frmLogin\"]/div[3]/button")).click();
    
    String mainwindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.out.println(handles);
    for(String handle:handles) 
     {
       driver.switchTo().window(handle);
       System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
     }
    driver.switchTo().window(mainwindow);
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://release01.curemd.com/curemd/datLogin.asp");
    //driver.get("https://release01.curemd.com/curemd/datCureMD.aspx");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"vchLogin_Name\"]")).sendKeys("zlive");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"vchPassword\"]")).sendKeys("1234");
    //*[@id="frmLogin"]/div[3]/button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"frmLogin\"]/div[3]/button")).click();

String selectAll =Keys.chord(Keys.ALT,"T");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"frmLogin\"]/div[3]/button")).sendKeys(selectAll);

//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"frmLogin\"]/div[3]/button")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL);
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"frmLogin\"]/div[3]/button")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

Comment: I have made changes as per suggestion but its still not working.